# gsutil: List only directories (bug?)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

```
$ gsutil ls -d 'gs://XXX/test/**/' 
gs://XXX/test/
gs://XXX/test/336x280.swf.gz
```

So it lists not only directories (ending with `/`) but also regular files (ending with `.gz` for instance).

But accordingly my understanding this command should list only directories. Where is the error?

```
$ gsutil --version
gsutil version: 4.27
```

Or is it a `gsutil` bug?

Answer (score 1):

That's certainly a bug with gsutil. Would you mind opening up an issue on GitHub?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues

In the mean time, a valid workaround would be piping the output to grep and checking for lines that end in `/`, e.g.:

```
gsutil ls -d <pattern> | grep "/$"
```

Comment: Opened an issue